# How to set background colour to the width containing text in flutter

Tags: text, flutter, dart, background

I have a text which is basically a title in a box and I want to provide a background color to the space behind that text .

```
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Text(
            'Your Profile',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.blue,
              fontSize: 26.0,                
              background: Paint()..color = Colors.blue,

            ),
```

This is what I tried but it seems not working.

Expected:Here 
"Your profile" text has a background color, I need to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Why dont you wrap it in a container and give container a background color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**:

```
Text(
  "Hello World",
  style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.blue), // give any color here
)
```

---

**Full answer**

[image]

You can use this in your `showDialog` call, Here is the full widget you were looking for.

```
Dialog(
  elevation: 12,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        color: Colors.blue[800],
        width: double.maxFinite,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
        child: Text(
          "Your Profile...",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 12),
            TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Select a Photo")),
            TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Take a Photo...")),
            TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Choose form Library")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
        child: RaisedButton(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
          child: Text("Back"),
          onPressed: () {},
          color: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: On click of back button I want it to go back for that I will have to use navigator.pop that will be having build context and here I m not having build context ..
I am calling the variable in showDialog .

onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => proDialog);
              },

Comment: @Prianca Can you please update your question with these details, it is bit difficult to understand in comment.

Comment: This is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56853595/showdialog-has-an-error-regarding-method-called-inside-it-in-flutter

Comment: Sir, I got the answer ..No need to check now Thank you so much

Comment: @Prianca I was about to answer it, but someone else already did that. Anyways, whenever you have any questions regarding `Flutter` and `Dart`, you can ask on SO and reach me using `@CopsOnRoad`, I will try my best to answer it.

Comment: Sure sir , I will definitely reach to you ..If you don't have any problem can I ask you if you ar on Twitter or any other site where you will be available.?

Comment: @Prianca I am sorry I don't have any twitter/facebook account. You can ask me whatever you want here on SO. if I know the solution, I'll definitely assist you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195902/discussion-between-prianca-and-copsonroad).

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap it with a `Container()` but, most probably you have to define the width with something like  `double.maxFinite`

**Check this**

```
Container(
width: double.maxFinite,
color: Colors.red, //define the background color
child: Text("My Text"),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Saeb Nabil's answer, the easiest way is to use a container. That way you can also control the padding around the text. You can also use `.withOpacity()` to add transparency if you wish:

```
Container(
   width: 100,
   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 10),
   color: Colors.grey[900].withOpacity(0.6),
   child: Text(
      "Hello world!",
      style: TextStyle(
         fontSize: 14,
         color: Colors.white),
   ), // Text
), // Container
```