# showDialog has an error regarding method called inside it in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `showDialog` method and that dialog is called inside `showDialog` (which will appear `onTap`). `showDialog` has red quickly lines on `proDialog` with some statement

This is the `Dialog` widget I am using :

```
WidgetBuilder  proDialog = (BuildContext context)  => Dialog(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[

        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Text(
            'Your Profile',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.blue,
              fontSize: 26.0,

            ),

          ),
        ),


        Container(color: Colors.black, height: 2),
        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Text(
              'Take a Photo',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 26.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),


        Container(color: Colors.black, height: 2),
        SizedBox(height: 8),
        RaisedButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 15.0),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.redAccent[800],
          child: Text('Back', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

This is where I am calling and getting some error on `proDialog`

[image: showDialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the dialog as the builder or call the builder:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: proDialog,
);
```

or

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => proDialog(context),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Widget proDialog = (BuildContext context)  => Dialog(
```

To

```
 Widget  proDialog  = Dialog(
```

Comment: No this is giving error stating that a value of type Dialog cant be assigned to a variable of type WidgetBuilder(build context) -> Widget'.

Comment: Changed to Widget